# I made an inequality to solve myself, but someone pointed out my solution is wrong.

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I made the following inequality for myself to solve, but [my friend](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/695001/isaac-yiu-math-studio) found out an mistake:

> If $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$ and $abc=1$, prove that $$\frac{a}{b+1}+\frac{b}{c+1}+\frac{c}{a+1}\ge\frac32$$

I tried to substitute $a=\frac xy, b= \frac yz, c= \frac zx$, but that friend found out a mistake. He wrote a solution using Muirhead’s inequality, but that is not what I want. I also tried trigonometric substitution, but it turned out that there is a mistake also. Is there any method which doesn’t use Muirhead’s inequality? Thanks for any help!

Comment: what does $cyc$ mean?

Comment: $cyc$ means cyclic.

Comment: ahh, I see. so you mean $\frac{a}{b+1} + \frac{b}{c+1} + \frac{c}{a+1}$. It would be easier for your question to be understood if you just wrote that out in the problem statement.

Comment: There is no point in asking cryptic questions.

Comment: It is now edited! :)

Comment: $a=-10, b=-{1 \over 10}, c=1$ gives a negative value.

Comment: @copper.hat Note the question says $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$, so your values of $a$ and $b$ are not valid.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Note that the question changed after it was asked. I was answering the original question asked.

Comment: Culver, that's me, who solve this by using muirhead

Answer (score 2):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab+a}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab+a)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$2(a+b+c)^2\geq3\sum_{cyc}(ab+a)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+ab)\geq3(a+b+c).$$
Now, by AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}ab\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=3$$ and by C-S again
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=\frac{1}{3}(1+1+1)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)^2.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)^2+3\geq3(a+b+c)$$ or
$$(2(a+b+c)-3)(a+b+c-3)\geq0.$$
Can you end it now?

Also, by AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+ab)\geq3\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{a^2\cdot a^2\cdot bc}=3(a+b+c).$$

Comment: $abc=1$ -> $a+b+c\ge 3$ -> $(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3(a+b+c)$.

Comment: @Quang Hoang Yes, of course!

Answer (score 0):

The friend he told in the problem was me, yeah. And I will post my solution by using the Muirhead Inequality (and also AM-GM Inequality).

$$\dfrac{a}{b+1}+\dfrac{b}{c+1}+\dfrac{c}{a+1}\ge\dfrac{3}{2} \\ \Updownarrow \\ a\left(a+1\right)\left(c+1\right)+b\left(b+1\right)\left(a+1\right)+c\left(c+1\right)\left(b+1\right)\ge\dfrac{3}{2}\left(a+1\right)\left(b+1\right)\left(c+1\right)\\ \Updownarrow \\ a^2c+b^2a+c^2b+a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca+a+b+c\ge\\\dfrac{3}{2}abc+\dfrac{3}{2}ab+\dfrac{3}{2}bc+\dfrac{3}{2}ca+\dfrac{3}{2}a+\dfrac{3}{2}b+\dfrac{3}{2}c+\dfrac{3}{2} \\ \Updownarrow (\text{Mutiply by 2 both side and rearranging})\\ 2a^2c+2b^2a+2c^2b+2a^2+2b^2+2c^2\ge3abc+ab+bc+ca+\left(a+b+c\right)a^\frac{1}{3}b^\frac{1}{3}c^\frac{1}{3}+3abc \\ \Updownarrow \\ \left(2a^2c+2b^2a+2c^2b-6abc\right)+\sum_{sym}\left(a^2-\dfrac{1}{2}ab-\dfrac{1}{2}a^\frac{4}{3}b^\frac{1}{3}c^\frac{1}{3}\right)\ge0 $$ By AM-GM Inequality, $$2a^2c+2b^2a+2c^2b\ge 3\sqrt[3]{8a^3b^3c^3}=6abc \\ \therefore 2a^2c+2b^2a+2c^2b-6abc\ge 0$$
By Muirhead Inequality,
$$\because \left(2,0,0\right)\succ\left(1,1,0\right),\left(2,0,0\right)\succ\left(\dfrac{4}{3},\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}\right) \\ \therefore \sum_{sym}\left(a^2-\dfrac{1}{2}ab-\dfrac{1}{2}a^\frac{4}{3}b^\frac{1}{3}c^\frac{1}{3}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{sym}\left(a^2-ab\right)+\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{sym}\left(a^2-a^\frac{4}{3}b^\frac{1}{3}c^\frac{1}{3}\right)\ge0$$
Adding the two inequality we prove, we get the answer.